# From Gitlab file URL, How to find out project path, branch name, folder and file name

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, gitlab-ce

Given a GitLab file full path, how to extract the project path, branch name ( brach name will have slash in it) and directory and file path.

eg:

Here is the full path of one file.

`https://gitlab.com/sfgroups-k8s/webapps/-/blob/feature/database/sql-scripts/select.sql?r`ef_type=heads`

From this need to extract:

```
project path: sfgroups-k8s/webapps
branch name: feature/database
file name: sql-scripts/select.sql
```

Branch name may or may not have slash in it. we can use gitlap API call if needed.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how the URL is consistently formatted, or how to extract that information using a script? If using a script, please post a copy of what you have so far and any errors.